# How to describe an event that was true in the past but not true any more?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request

I want to describe that I joined a newly opened college (it was new a decade ago, but no longer new). How to describe this to warn the reader that it is no longer new?

> In 2000, I joined the newly (at that time) opened university XYZ.

Is the phrase **[at that time**] correctly placed? Is there any better alternative to warn the reader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Then*** is your saviour here.

> In 2000, I joined the then newly opened university XYZ.

***then*** - at that time; at the time in question.

It points to a specific time/event in the past.

More examples:

> I was still in school then when the attacks happened.
>
> The play rules were different then.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think your sentence is ok without the parenthetical clarification.  Simply:

> In 2000, I joined the newly opened university XYZ.

In more complex cases, you could clarify with a dependent clause:

> In 2000, I joined the university XYZ, which had just received a 1st place ranking by AAA Reports.

(Note if you replace "had" with "has", the timeframe would change from 2000 to now)